# How to upload File in Selenium Java on Linux Server (Headless Mode)

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, pipeline

Scenario: **Selenium-Java Linux**
When Click on Upload Button, Explorer will open.
Then need to Paste Path & Need to Click Open.

Same is working in Windows using Robot/Sikuli/AutoIt

But tried different way to execute same in Linus Server but Failed. Any Leads  ??

Not uploading fine in Linux Server

I don't have input tag

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file using Selenium in Java is a common task, and the process is generally the same whether you're running your tests on a local machine or on a Linux server. However, there are a few considerations specific to running tests on a server.
1-Set Up WebDriver.
2-Locate the File Input Element.
3-Send File Path to Input Element.
this example
`WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.id("fileInputId")); fileInput.sendKeys("/path/to/your/file.txt");`

4-Submit the Form (if required).
try this .`WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.id("formId")); form.submit();` 
5- Handle Any File Upload Dialog (if present).
Here's an example using Robot class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
StringSelection stringSelection =new StringSelection("/path/to/your/file.txt");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```